# Centering the pagination div

Tags: html, position, centering

Normally the pagination looks like this:

[image]

When I will add something like:

`<td align="center">`
or `<center><div id="pagination></div></center>`

It looks like this:

[image]

I've tried also to use `style="margin: 0px auto;"` but it not work.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div id="pagination"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Yes, I've also tried to use this attributes on the div (including `text-align: center;`).

CSS Part:

```
.jPaginate{
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
    color:#a5a5a5;
    font-size:small;   
    width:100%;
}
.jPaginate a{
    line-height:15px;
    height:18px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
}
.jPag-control-back{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
}
.jPag-control-front{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
.jPaginate span{
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.jPag-pages{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul.jPag-pages li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
ul.jPag-pages li a{
    float:left;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
span.jPag-current{
    cursor:default;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:15px;
    height:18px;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
}
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-previous,
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-next,
span.jPag-sprevious,
span.jPag-snext,
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-previous-img,
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-next-img,
span.jPag-sprevious-img,
span.jPag-snext-img{
    height:22px;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
    line-height:18px;
}

ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-previous,
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-previous-img{
    margin:2px 0px 2px 2px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
        width:10px;

}
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-next,
ul.jPag-pages li span.jPag-next-img{
    margin:2px 2px 2px 0px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:10px;
}
span.jPag-sprevious,
span.jPag-sprevious-img{
    margin:2px 0px 2px 2px;
    font-size:18px;
    width:15px;
    text-align:right;
}
span.jPag-snext,
span.jPag-snext-img{
    margin:2px 2px 2px 0px;
    font-size:18px;
    width:15px;
     text-align:right;
}
```

This is the HTML output from the Firebug:

```
<div id="pagination" class="jPaginate" style="padding-left: 71px; ">
            <div class="jPag-control-back">
                <a class="jPag-first" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(212,                   192, 161); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px;   border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-right-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-bottom-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-left-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); ">First</a>
                <span class="jPag-sprevious">«</span>
           </div>
           <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; width: 101px; ">
               <ul class="jPag-pages" style="width: 99px; ">
                  <li><a style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(212, 192, 161); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-right-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-bottom-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-left-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); ">1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <span class="jPag-current" style="color: rgb(0, 99, 220); background-color: rgb(241, 224, 198); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(141, 4, 4); border-right-color: rgb(141, 4, 4); border-bottom-color: rgb(141, 4, 4); border-left-color: rgb(141, 4, 4); ">2</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <a style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(212, 192, 161); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-right-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-bottom-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-left-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); ">3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(212, 192, 161); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-right-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-bottom-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-left-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); ">4</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="jPag-control-front" style="left: 176px; ">
             <span class="jPag-snext">»</span>
             <a class="jPag-last" style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(212, 192, 161); border-top-width: 1px; border-right-width: 1px; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-right-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-bottom-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); border-left-color: rgb(98, 36, 0); ">Last</a>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide css part.

Comment: @Avinash Done, also included the firebug output.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you the link where I got my solution from then the relevant part of my source code.

Link:

[Centering menus](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/centered.html)

> All we need to do is enclose the ul tag in an outer container that has a width of 100% and overflow set to hidden.
>   The ul tag is then styled with a relative position and floated left with a left position of 50%.
>   Finally the li tag is also styled with a relative position, floated left but this time with a right position of 50%.
>   ...and that as they say is all that is needed.kquote

My HTML:

```
<div class="menuholder fleft">
    <ul class="mainmenu fleft">
        <li class="fleft"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="fleft"><a href="b.html">B</a></li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.menuholder
{
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;        
}

.mainmenu
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.mainmenu li
{
    position: relative;
    right: 50%;
}

.mainmenu a
{
    width: auto;
    display: block;        
}

.fleft
{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you my method to right-align. First You should wrap your div in another div with class "pagination-wrapper-right". And after that write correct css styles.
In my case i'll show to you my scss styles ))

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 pagination">
  <div class="pagination-wrapper-right">
      <div class="page-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where div.page-pagination - jPagination block
div.pagination-wrapper-right - where wrapper for alignment

after we can write css styles:

```
.pagination-wrapper-right{
   clear: both;
   float: right;
 }
.jPaginate{
  padding-left: 62px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 62px;
}
```

Try it self and good luck

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating tables try to edit pagination class inside your CSS and set its left and right margins to auto

have a look here

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the jPaginate class like this::

```
    .jPaginate{
    height:34px;
    position:relative;
    color:#a5a5a5;
    font-size:small;   
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```